# Unity C# camera zoom script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So before I explain my problem. I will first tell what I am really doing.
I am working on a click to move/zoom camera script. There are 3 planes in front of my Main Camera. Now what I am doing is, creating a script which says " The camera will zoom on the plane which gets clicked. I made several attempts to come up with a working script but it didn't worked well. Every time I come across new bugs , errors and what not. :|
I got frustrated and deleted the buggy script. Now I want to start from scratch. I am doing it in C#

Since I am not a professional, Can anyone explain me in detail to get it done?
I am confused how to deal with the planes I placed. I want to know what is missing in my script. 
Here is a screenshot of how I placed those planes.

[image]

Edit. - I managed to work on it. Now I need advice, how to target the planes I placed in front of the camera.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraZoom : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int zoomLevelSelected = 0;
    public float[] ZoomLevels = new float[] { 60, 40, 20 };
    void Update()
    {
        int zoomChange = 0;
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) { zoomChange = +1; } // back
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) { zoomChange = -1; } // forward
        if (zoomChange != 0)
        {
            zoomLevelSelected = Mathf.Clamp(zoomLevelSelected + zoomChange, 0, ZoomLevels.Length - 1);
            camera.fieldOfView = ZoomLevels[zoomLevelSelected];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A couple of things.  To select the planes, use [Physics.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html)(Docs should explain the basics).  Next, don't change the field of view to zoom, that's going to mess up your view.  Instead, move your camera's transform.position.

Answer (score 1):

Heck with it, here is one way to create a click zoom.  The gist is that you create a ray from your camera in to the scene through the mouse cursor.  When that ray intersects an object create a second ray from the point of intersection back out along the intersecting face's normal.

```
void Update () {
    if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)){
        // get ray from camera in to scene at the mouse position
        Ray ray = Camera.mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        // hardcoded "zoom" distance.
        float zoomDist = 15.0f;

        // Raycast from camera to mouse cursor, if object hit, zoom.
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit,Mathf.Infinity)){       
            // Create a second ray from the hit object back out, zoom the camera along this ray.
            Ray r = new Ray(hit.point,hit.normal);
            Camera.mainCamera.transform.position = r.GetPoint(zoomDist);
        }
    }
}
```

Things to keep in mind:

1. [Physics.Raycast](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html), as written, will return true for any GameObject with a collider.  Use [layers](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/Layers.html) if you only want to zoom when selecting specific GameObjects.
2. The camera won't directly center on the GameObject you click.  I use the exact point of intersection to create the position where the camera will zoom to.
3. zoomDist is the distance away from the object.
4. This code only works with perspective cameras, if you use orthographic you'll need to modify the `size` value of the camera to zoom.

Comment: I also would recommend iTween library if you want the smooth camera movement. It would be something like iTween.MoveTo(Camera.mainCamera.gameObject, r.GetPoint(zoomDist));

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your script is that your var int zoomChange is getting set to zero every frame so move that variable to class level.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CameraZoom : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int zoomLevelSelected = 0;
    public float[] ZoomLevels = new float[] { 60, 40, 20 };
    int zoomChange = 0;  //<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0)) { zoomChange = +1; } // back
        else if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1)) { zoomChange = -1; } // forward
        if (zoomChange != 0)
        {
            zoomLevelSelected = Mathf.Clamp(zoomLevelSelected + zoomChange, 0, ZoomLevels.Length - 1);
            camera.fieldOfView = ZoomLevels[zoomLevelSelected];
        }
    }
}
```